# Putting Python 3.5 and 3.6 into path and switching between them in command prompt

Tags: python, windows, python-3.x, command-prompt

I seek to be able to type something like

`python36`

or

`python35`

in the command prompt to be be able to run 3.6 or 3.5 shells, respectively. When I type python in the command prompt, it only opens a 3.5 shell, and if I try to specify 3.6 by typing `python3.6` or `python3.5` or `python36` or `python35`, it doesn't recognize the commands. For both installations, I checked the "Add to my path" box, and have since tried to manually add them to my path using system settings/advanced/environment variables, etc, but it's not clear to me how to best do this.

I am using Windows 7.

Comment: Which operating system are you talking about?

Comment: What system are you on? This may be better suited for [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/).

Comment: Are you trying to type `python3.6` into a Python 3.5 interpreter? That's not a Python command. Get out of Python first.

Comment: I'm just in a blank command prompt, not in a shell.

Comment: This wouldn't directly answer your question but have you considered creating virtual environments using either virtualenv or anaconda? Having either of those will make it easier to use and manage two separate environments

Comment: @JohnnyApple for future reference, the Windows Command Prompt *is a CLI shell*. The Python interpreter can open a REPL (Read-Evaluate-Print-Loop) session *in the shell*, sometimes called an "interactive interpreter session" or just "the Python interpreter" depending on context.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga, python.exe does not open the REPL "in the shell". It executes attached to the console that's inherited from the shell using standard I/O file handles for the console input and screen buffers. The shell is just waiting waiting in the background for python.exe to exit before it resumes as the foreground process attached to the console.

Comment: @eryksun yes, thank you for the correction. My language was sloppy, even as I was trying to make a terminology point. It is always good to be precise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add both folders to your environment variables and then copy each `python.exe` to `python35.exe` or `python36.exe` depending on version.

Then you can execute it using `python35` or `python36` to execute different versions.

For example:

- Navigate to python3.5 folder
- Look for `python.exe` file and make a copy of it named `python35.exe`
- You can use `python35` in cmd now to run 3.5 version of Python

Do the same for 3.6 and you're done.

Comment: What do you mean by "copy each `python.exe`..."?

Comment: Navigate to python folder and look for `python.exe` and make a copy of it named `python35.exe` for the 3.5 version and same for 3.6

Comment: So, I can go to my system variables, find the "Path" variables, add C:\Python36 and C:\Python35-32, and then copy the executables in each folder and rename them as you suggested? Do I need to add anything else to the path, like specific subfolders?

Comment: Nope, you need to add python folder only.

Answer (score 2):

If you followed anything close to a normal installation process, you will have installed the [Python Launcher for Windows](https://docs.python.org/3/using/windows.html#python-launcher-for-windows). This is invoked by the `py` command. To run a particular version of installed Python, use `-` followed by the version:

```
py -3.6
```

or

```
py -3.5
```

When invoked without any parameters, `py` will call the "default" Python, which would be whichever one you installed last.